# How to access data from amazon page and replace with the converted values using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So what I wanna do is to get CAD from amazon.ca and convert them into INR. Now I've figured out how to get data from amazon.ca using a dummy page on localhost and apply the converted value, but the thing is, IDK how to apply it so that it starts converting and replacing the data from amazon.ca instead of localhost. The folowing is what I did till now.

content.js

```
async function exchangeCurrency() {
// Fetchs INR and puts in curVal
var url = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/cad.json"
let obj = await(await fetch(url)).json()
var curVal = obj.cad["inr"]


// Gets CAD Dollar and Cents
var cadPriceWhole = document.getElementsByClassName("a-price-whole")
var cadPriceFraction = document.getElementsByClassName("a-price-fraction")

for(var i = 0; i<cadPriceWhole.length; i++){
    var wCAD = parseInt(cadPriceWhole[i].innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''))
    var fCAD = parseInt(cadPriceFraction[i].innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''))

    var inr = parseInt((wCAD + (fCAD/100)) * curVal)

    cadPriceFraction[i].innerHTML = ""
    cadPriceWhole[i].innerHTML = cadPriceWhole[i].innerHTML + " - " + inr.toLocaleString()
}
}
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    console.log("Poopz Here")
    exchangeCurrency()
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Amzn CAD-INR",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Convert CAD to INR in Amazon",
"manifest_version": 3,
"author": "AZZIOI"
}
```

dummy page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <span class="a-price-whole">1,279<span class="a-price-decimal">.</span></span>
    <span class="a-price-whole">879<span class="a-price-decimal">.</span></span>
    <span class="a-price-whole">989<span class="a-price-decimal">.</span></span>
    
    <span class="a-price-fraction">78</span>
    <span class="a-price-fraction">45</span>
    <span class="a-price-fraction">69</span>



</body>
<script src="content.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use content_scripts.

For example:

manifest.jsion

```
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.amazon.ca/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "matches.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}}
```

matches.js

```
Write your script here.
```

Comment: Sure... I'll check it later on and update on the issue